# How to get input from user until he want to stop using may be delimeter or anothor way using filestream in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get input from user it may be paragraph but until user want to quit and after this input store on text file in console application c#.

Comment: Show us what you have tried on your requirement

Comment: I just want to write file and content must be user input.input may be paragraph or any number text but after press q(quit) its exit and content store into file.

Comment: Yeah,That's we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. *Without trying your version, it is of no use on your learning path.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SampleNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var currentLine = string.Empty;
            var completeText = string.Empty;
            while(true)
            {
                currentLine = Console.ReadLine();
                if(currentLine.Trim().ToLower() == "q")
                    break;
                else
                    completeText += currentLine + Environment.Newline;
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"<FullpathForFile>", completeText);
        }
    }
}
```